# Swift - Thumbnail creation Memory Crash

Tags: ios, xcode, swift2

I am creating thumbnails for the photos in Photo library using `PHImageManager`. and in the write method, I am converting the returned image to data. When I comment `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` and `UIImagePNGRepresentation`, the memory is stable.

In iPad with iOS 10.0 and above, I am observing a huge memory consumption and finally crash without any logs. For all other OS versions (below 10.0), the memory is stable and no crash is observed.

I have added a sample code below

```
fun generateAndSaveThumbnail() {

    let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestOptions.synchronous = true
    requestOptions.deliveryMode = .FastFormat
    requestOptions.networkAccessAllowed = true

    for item in 0..<fetchResult.count {
        if let asset = fetchResult[item] as? PHAsset {
            if let fileName = asset.valueForKey("filename") as? String {
                if fileExistAtPath(path) == false {
                    PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize: thumbnailSize, contentMode: PHImageContentMode.AspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: { (image, _) in
                        MyFileManager().writeThumbnailImage(image, imageName: fileName)
                    })
                } else {
                    //File exist at path
                }
            } else {
                //File name missing
            }
        } else {
            //asset error
        }
    }
}

func writeThumbnailImage(image: UIImage?, imageName: String) -> Bool {
    if image == nil {
        return false
    }

    var imageData: NSData? = nil
    if imageName.capitalizedString.containsString(kJPGExt) {
        print("JPG Image conversion")
        imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image!, 0.8)
    } else {
        print("PNG Image conversion")
        imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image!)
    }
    if imageData != nil {
        let path = getFilePathForType(mediaType, imageName: imageName)
        return writeDataToPath(path, data: imageData)
    } 
    return false
}
```

The memory keeps rising and finaly receives the following message in the console

```
Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is this code part of a class? A common mistake isis that you have a retain cycle or a memory leak when grabbing the data from closure and passing into the method. Are you calling self maybe? Give us some more information. UIImageJPEGRepresentation is not causing the memory leak here. Where is `image_` defined?

Comment: image_ was a typo. This is a method in a class, except for writeThumbnailImage which is a class method in a different utility class.

We iterate through the fetch results. And why is this observed in iPad with OS 10.0 alone